# Construct a table, where it is cut in the middle with zigzag path in the ends

Tags: tables

Please, see the picture below

[image]

I know I should provide a code what I have tried, but I do not know how in this case. I believe I should use the tabular enviroment, but then maybe something needs to overlay in the middle. How exactly, I do not know. Perhaps I should use tikz to do it? However, I do not think this approach is effective due to the size of the overlaying when you make a longer table.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possibility with `nicematrix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{|l|c|ccc|c|}[standard-cline]\cline{1-3}\cline{5-6}
\Block{}{Antal \r{a}r efter\\1938} & 0 & 1 & \hspace{3mm} & 74 & 75\\ \cline{1-3}\cline{5-6}
\Block{}{Antal\\trompet\'ertraner} & 18 & 22 & & 279 & 304\\ \cline{1-3}\cline{5-6}
\CodeAfter
  \tikz
    \draw[gray!30, decorate, decoration={zigzag, amplitude=2pt, segment length=7pt}] (1-|4)--(3-|4)(1-|5)--(3-|5);
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

> [image: Blockquote]

with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            %\draw[gray!15] (0,0) grid (14,4);
            \draw (8.5,0)--(0,0)--(0,3)--(8.5,3);
            \draw (9.5,0)--(13,0)--(13,3)--(9.5,3);
            \draw (0,1.5)--(8.5,1.5) (9.5,1.5)--(13,1.5);
            \foreach \x in {5.5,7,10,11.5}
                \draw (\x,0)--(\x,3);
            \draw[decorate,decoration=snake] (8.5,0)--(8.5,3);
            \draw[decorate,decoration=snake] (9.5,0)--(9.5,3);
            \node[text width=4cm,align=left] at (2.5,2.3) {\LARGE Antal ar efter 1938};
            \foreach \x/\t in {6.25/0,7.75/1,10.75/74,12.25/75}
                \node at (\x,2.3) {\LARGE \t};
            \node[text width=4cm,align=left] at (2.5,.8) {\LARGE Antal trompetertraner};
            \foreach \x/\t in {6.25/18,7.75/22,10.75/279,12.25/304}
                \node at (\x,.8) {\LARGE \t};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```